# Bazel: submodule in project does not use bazel , pushing to git doesnt include locally added BUILD file in submodule, how do i build?

Tags: c++, c, git, build, bazel

I am just starting to learn how to use bazel following this [tutorial](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/tutorial/cpp.html)

One thing I am unsure how to do is how to use a submodule, from my own repo for example. where I do not use bazel. The repo just has some c/h files that I need to pull in. To make things work locally I added a BUILD file in folder pulled in from submodules. However after I commit and push my changes the BUILD file is obviously not there. How do I add the c/h files from the submodule folder to my build. Bazel seems to be looking for a BUILD folder in that directory and there will be none, if for example someone else clones this repo.

currently my "main" Directory has this build file:

```
cc_library(
  name = "uCShell-main",
  srcs = ["main.c"],
  deps = ["//uCShell:uCShell-lib" ],
)

cc_binary(
   name = "uCShell-bin",
   deps = [":uCShell-main" , "//uCShell:uCShell-lib" ]
)
```

and the folder with the pulled in submodule has this locally added BUILD file:

```
cc_library(
    name = "uCShell-lib",
    srcs = glob(["*.c"]),
    hdrs = glob(["*.h"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

This works and compiles just fine. However do correct any issues or misuse of Bazel you see here, I'd like to learn.
Ultimately to reiterate the issue, when I push this project the locally added BUILD file will not be in the project because it is not in the original submodule. So how can I inlcude the c/h files in that submodule in order to build my main. And I would like to leave it as a submodule. Ultimately I can just add a BUILD file for the submodule's repo, but would like to find a better way, for example what if this was not my repo where I can just add a BUILD file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [new_local_repository](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/workspace.html#new_local_repository) with a relative path to import the submodule, you can set `build_file` or `build_file_content` to add the BUILD file. You should be able to use that same  BUILD file as-is.

Because it will be in a different [external repository](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/external.html), you'll need to access it via the corresponding label.

For example, if you put the BUILD file at `build/BUILD.my_lib.bazel` and this in WORKSPACE:

```py
new_local_repository(
    name = "my_lib",
    path = "submodules/my_lib",
    build_file = "@//build:BUILD.my_lib.bazel",
)
```

then you can put `@my_lib//:uCShell-lib` in `deps` of any other target and it will all work.

Comment: just tried this and it works thanks a lot!!!! @[Brian Silverman]